# Studying the monotony of an integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to understand the following exercise:

Be $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, such that $f(x) \ge 0,\forall x \ge0$

Study the monotonicity of the following function: $g(x) := \int_{0}^{x^2} f(t)dt$

I'm still new to integrals and I'm lost on how should I start solving this.
Any tips are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.  $g'(x) \ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: You need to prove or disprove $g(x) \le g(y)$ holds for every $x\le y$. So, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the FTC, if $\;F(x)\;$ is a primitive of $\;f\;$ (it exists since $\;f\;$ is continuous), then

$$\int_0^{x^2}f(t)\,dt=F(x^2)-F(0)\implies\left(\int_0^{x^2}f(t)\,dt\right)'=\left(F(x^2)-F(0)\right)'\stackrel{\text{chain rule}}=2xF'(x^2)$$

Well, can you now say something about the sign of $\;g'(x)\;$ and thus about monotony of $\;g\;$ ?